# When to sort lists client | server | database?

Tags: asp.net, client-server

I am working on a work-order system that is web based.

The database for tickets is in SQL, it is queried with C#, then passed to jquery (C# MVC).

For some circumstances, sorting the tickets is highly beneficial, such as in most recently opened order.  However, being new to web development, I am unsure of when I should sort the ticket list.

For efficiency, is it best to query the tables in ascending/descending order, sort the queried list in C# and then hand it to JQuery, or sort it once it is obtained by jquery?

With all the client versus server side chitchat out there I am rather confused as to what to do and when to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way in this case is always sort and filter the data in database with index. You can consider creating view/stored procedure or using [OData](http://www.odata.org/) for the different circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

It depend on the jquery control used in UI part.
For example if you are  using jquery grid that already have sorting feature and if that feature is on. Then we have to prefer shorting using jquery option. Because if we get sorted result from db and pass to jquery grid where shorting already enable. Then it will changes the sorting order return by db.
But yes if there is no support available on jquery tool for sorting then we can get sorted data from db.